# Siblings with entry_id not in another relationship field

Tags: ee2, channel-entries

Can't figure this out.

I'm using EE2 and I have a channel called products and I'm on a single product page. I have a relationship field for products set up called featured_products, which I am displaying in a list. I can do that fine. They're basically related products.

I, then, want to have a see more button that displays another list of ALL other products (siblings), EXCEPT that list should exclude the ones that are already in featured_products.

I tried using siblings, to no avail:

```
{siblings 
    entry_id="not {entry_id}
              {featured_products}
                 |{featured_products:entry_id}
              {/featured_products}"
}
```

and that didn't work because I guess "field" is the only siblings arg.

I tried using an embed and doing something like:

```
{embed="products/.more-products" 
    notproducts="
    {entry_id}
    {featured_products}
        |{featured_products:entry_id}
    {/featured_products}"}
```

and then in that embed had something like

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" entry_id="not {embed:notproducts}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

which for reasons I can't understand, only showed one product, the product whose page I was on.

Pretty sure I'm just approaching this wrong. HALP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your embed solution should work, but you probably need to add `dynamic="no"` to the channel entries call ([see docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic)).

HTH